# Problem applying Where and Take in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<MediaRef>` and i want to apply Take and Where condition on it but it is not working i wonder what is the issue. My query is

```
List<MediaRef> objmed = new List<MediaRef>();
objmed = GetRecords(); //GetRecords will fetch records
objmed.Where(e => e.Title.Contains(Keyword)) //This line is not working
```

and Where condition is not working but when i change this to

```
List<MediaRef> objmed = new List<MediaRef>();
objmed = GetRecords();
objmed = (from p in objmed 
         where p.Title.Contains(Keyword)
         select p).ToList();
```

It works fine. I am facing same problem using `Take()` function. What may be the problem?

Comment: define `not working`! does an exception occure? what is the result - how does it differ from the expected one? btw ... you should care about `return types`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> objmed.Where(e => e.Title.Contains(Keyword)) //This line is not working

You need to assign the result, the `Were` operator doesn't change the source collection, it creates a lazy output collection.

When you enumerate the result of `Where` it will read the source collection and return the elements that match the condition. In your working example you are (1) assigning the result, and (2) using `ToList` to force enumeration.

Try:

```
// No need to create a List<> only to throw it away
List<MediaRef> objmed = GetRecords();
objmed = objmed.Where(e => e.Title.Contains(Keyword)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<MediaRef> objmed = new List<MediaRef>();
objmed = GetRecords(); //GetRecords will fetch records
objmed = objmed.Where(e => e.Title.Contains(Keyword));
```

You forgot to assign the result of where to something.

Comment: This won't compile - you'll need a ToList() after that the Where()

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var records = GetRecords().Where(e => e.Title.Contains(Keyword)).ToList();
```

The `ToList()` is unnecessary if you are going to enumerate the list with `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the output of where to a new variable - e.g.

```
var withWhere = objmed.Where(e => e.Title.Contains(Keyword));
var withTakeAndWhere = withWhere.Take(10);
```

or, of course you can use fluid styling:

```
List<MediaRef> objmed = 
       GetRecords()
          .Where(e => e.Title.Contains(Keyword))
          .Take(10)
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? The .Where and .Take methods return a list of objects depending on the criteria given.

The code should be:

```
List<MediaRef> objmed = new List<MediaRef>();
objmed = GetRecords(); //GetRecords will fetch records
objmed = objmed.Where(e => e.Title.Contains(Keyword)) //This line is not working
```